# Why doesn't English have contracted forms for past tense verbs?

Tags: verbs, american-english

In English, we contract things like "They are" to "They're." As far as I know, for indicative moods, this is only done for present and future tense verbs. Why is it not done for past tense (I know there are things like "they've", but we still do not contract, for example, "He was.")

Comment: I assume you mean specifically "was" and "were", since "had" clearly contracts. I don't agree with your judgments, but I grant that normatively, contraction of "I+was X" is sloppy speech, and occurs less often than "he+is X" contraction. Contraction of "he+was" is more common, but you can't distinguish "he+was" from "he+is" or "he+has".

Comment: There are ways to contract past auxiliaries that haven't been blessed with apostolic apostrophic contractions. If one says, for instance, _He was there_, a common contracted pronunciation would be [hiw'zer]. Of course there's no standard way to spell this, but contraction is a feature of speech, not writing.